# Import random in python

Tags: python

I'm practicing coding in python and my current project is a game. So I'm trying to create a console game that prints shuffled letters and players have to create a word using that letters. My plan is to have a different level. And per level, I have different sets of shuffled letters that will be used randomly.

Here is my code:

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, key):
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
    self.val = key

def printPreorder(root):
    if root:
        print(root.val),
        printPreorder(root.left)
        printPreorder(root.right)

 class stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def push(self, item):
        return self.items.append(item)

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

#1st possible set for level 1
print('WELCOME TO LEVEL 1')
print ("Create 3 words using the letters:")
root = Node('n')
root.right = Node('o')
root.left = Node ('w')
printPreorder(root)
s1 = stack()
while (s1.size() <3):
    FirstList = (input("Enter the word you created: ")).lower()
    if FirstList == 'won' or FirstList == 'own' or FirstList == 'now':
        s1.push(FirstList)
        print(s1.items)

#2nd possible set for level 1
print('WELOCME TO LEVEL 1!')
print ("Create 3 words using the letters:")
root = Node('a')
root.right = Node('r')
root.left = Node ('e')
printPreorder(root)
s1 = stack()
while (s1.size() <3):
    SecondList1 = (input("Enter the word you created: ")).lower()
    if SecondList == 'ear' or SecondList == 'are' or SecondList == 'era':
        s1.push(SecondList)
        print(s1.items)
```

How can I randomly print/use just one between the two?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `random.choice`

```
import random
selected_list = random.choice((FirstList,SecondList))
print(selected_list)
```

the variable `selected_list`  will randomly be either FirstList or SecondList. You can pass any number of lists into the function.